# See if a customer had a purchase across every quarter and then graph

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
 customer_id|date      |sales_amount
 479485     |20190120  | 500         
 479485     |20180320  | 200           
 472848     |20191020  | 100
```

This data has transaction information from 2016-2019. For each business quarter (grouped by 3 months) I want to see if a unique customer had a transaction. Basically I want the y-axis for the table to be each unique customer_id and then the x-axis of the table to be the 12 quarters in the time period of the data with a Boolean of whether or not a customer had a transaction in that quarter.

Ultimately I want to visualize this data to see the distribution of the transactions for each quarter across all the unique customers.

Expect output:

```
 customer_id|2017- Q1  |2017- Q2|.. |2019- Q4
 479485     |20190120  |   0    |.. |   1 
 469488     |20180320  |   0    |.. |   0  
 452848     |20191020  |   1    |.. |   1
```

I have changed the date column to datetime but am unsure how to group and proceed to the next step.

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['customer_id'],df['date']).gt(0)`? if not show an example of expected output for this dataframe

Comment: 1) Make sure `date` is `datetime` type. 2) get quarter by `df.groupby([df['customer_id'], df['date'].dt.quarter])['sales_amount'].count().unstack('customer_id', fill_value=0).plot.bar()`?

Comment: @ansev please see the example output above

Comment: @QuangHoang this is giving me the customer ids as a header where I want the count per quarter for each unique customer as shown above.

Comment: Replace `'customer_id'` inside `unstack` with `date`?

Comment: @QuangHoang that help but i need to be able to separate every quarter. That is what i am getting stuck on. I want the count of rows for each quarter in the 2 year window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
df.groupby([df['customer_id'], df['date'].apply(lambda _: pd.Period(_, 'Q'))])['sales_amount'].count().unstack().fillna(0)
```

**Output:**

```
       date 2017Q1  2018Q1  2019Q1  2019Q4
customer_id             
469471      1.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
469488      0.0     1.0     1.0     1.0
472848      0.0     0.0     0.0     1.0
479485      1.0     1.0     1.0     0.0
```

**Notes**

- Assumptions: (1) all of the year-quarters appear in you data set, and (2) there's only a single transaction per quarter.
- To get around (1), set the index as `date`, and reindex with missing dates, filling nans with zero values. The above output is based on a sample of dummy data, hence only four quarters are shown.
- To get around (2), run [`np.sign(_)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) over your output.